# How can I get coordinates of taped pin to calculate distance between user location and pin

Tags: ios, xcode, annotations, location, distance

I have a lot of annotations on my mapview and I need to calculate distance from user location to taped annotation. How can that be done?

MyAnnotation

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

    if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]])
    {
        return nil;
    }

    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";

    MKAnnotationView *pinView = [aMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];

    if (pinView == nil)
    {
        pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];


    }
    else
        pinView.annotation = annotation;

    MyAnnotation *myAnn = (MyAnnotation *)annotation;
    pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:myAnn.icon];

    return pinView;

}
```

To calculate I use

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

    CLLocation *pinLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:37.322998 longitude:-122.032182];

    NSLog(@"New Location:%@", newLocation);
    CLLocationDistance distance = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:pinLocation];
    NSLog(@"Distance to pin %4.0f", distance);

}
```

**But how can I get pin coordinates automatically when annotation taped?**

EDIT:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    CLLocation *pinLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[(MyAnnotation*)[view annotation] coordinate].latitude longitude:[(MyAnnotation*)[view annotation] coordinate].longitude];

    CLLocation *userLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    CLLocationDistance distance = [pinLocation distanceFromLocation:userLocation];
    NSLog(@"Distance to pin %4.0f", distance);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement [`mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView%3aannotationView%3acalloutAccessoryControlTapped%3a), which will give you an `MKAnnotationView` when a pin is tapped. This annotation view has an `annotation` property, which has a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. From the coordinate, make a `CLLocation` and combine with your other location to get the distance using `distanceFromLocation`.

Comment: You'll learn much better if you go through it yourself. Just follow the trail of properties.

Comment: I have already - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{ } but I can't find out how to combine CLLocationCoordinate2D, CLLocation

Comment: Can you look at edited question? It worked, but only when I tap rightCalloutAccessoryView button

Comment: That code looks fine. It's supposed to work with the right button. It sounds like you got it working, no?

Comment: Well it can work with the left callout view too, if it's a `UIControl` subclass. Read the docs I linked to for more info. If you want to do it completely without a button you could use `– mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:` but it's a bit strange.

Comment: Is that supposed to be MKAnnotation instead of MyAnnotation?  Im getting errors at this line: `    CLLocation *pinLocation = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[(MKAnnotationView*)[view annotation] coordinate].latitude longitude:[(MKAnnotationView*)[view annotation] coordinate].longitude]];
`

Comment: @marciokoko The `MyAnnotation` is a cast and will only work if you are also using an annotation subclass called `MyAnnotation`.

Comment: I posted my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250311/how-to-add-distance-to-pin-of-an-mkannotation  My location objects are actually from MyLocation (NSObject subclass) which adopts the MKAnnotation protocol.  I have moved on since last night, could you take a look at my post and help me figure out what Im missing...im almost there :) thx